# Compiling Java on linux javac - failure on order of Jar files

Tags: java, servlets, jar, javac

I am trying to compile a Java servlet which uses multiple external jars. Javac recognises the first jar, but then spits out errors that it can't find the following jars. When I swap the order, it still recognises the first, but none after. The command line I am using;

> javac -classpath ~/servlet/servlet-api-2.3.jar:~/servlet/gson-2.2.2.jar:~/servlet/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar ~/servlet/dataExchange.java ~/servlet/dbUserConnect.java ~/servlet/dbTTConnect.java -d $TOMCAT_HOME

As you can see I am trying to use the servlet jar, Googles GSON (JSON), MySQL & Oracle Jars.

If you need any other information just ask.
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At least one mistake:

```
Usage: javac <options> <source files>
```

Your command line is:

```
Usage: javac <options> <source files> <options>
```

Try this:

```
javac -classpath ~/servlet/servlet-api-2.3.jar:~/servlet/gson-2.2.2.jar:~/servlet/mysql-connector-java-5.1.22-bin.jar -d $TOMCAT_HOME ~/servlet/dataExchange.java ~/servlet/dbUserConnect.java ~/servlet/dbTTConnect.java
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is the use of the ~ character throughout the path.   Only the instance at the beginning of the option will be expanded.